# Parse currency with symbol: Not all case working - Java

Tags: java, currency

I am using `java.text.NumberFormat` to parse String currency which has currency symbol. It is working for some cases while fails for other.

```
NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(Locale.FRANCE).parse("1 599,99 €"); //fails
NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(Locale.FRANCE).parse("599,99 €"); //works fine
```

Can somebody please explain why it is not working in first case?
Is Joda-Money a better library for such type of parsing?

Comment: I am not sure but like to suggested:it seems space between the 1 and 5 in first statement is not valid for currency representation.

Comment: might be a problem with space in `1 599,99`. Have you tried it without space?

Comment: But I think space is in their format. For e.g. this Google shopping page has that format of price. http://tinyurl.com/k33oezz

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason that this might not work for you, is usage of invalid white space character.

The format class expect the char with code 160 witch is describe as "Non-breaking space", when you may pass the code 30 witch is "Space".

You can run this code to check it.

```
NumberFormat currencyInstance = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(Locale.FRANCE);

String france = "1 599,99 €";
String format = currencyInstance.format(1599.99);
Number number = currencyInstance.parse(format);


System.out.println("France: " + format);
System.out.println("Format: " + format);
System.out.println("Number: " + number);

if(france.equals(format)) {
    number = currencyInstance.parse(france); // Must work;
    System.out.println(number);
} else {

    char[] fr = france.toCharArray();
    char[] ft = format.toCharArray();

    for(int i = 0; i < fr.length; i++) {
        if(fr[i] != ft[i]) {
            System.out.printf("The value on position %d are not equal. France: %d; Format: %d", i,(int)fr[i], (int)ft[i]);
        }
    }

}
```

Then environment details:

```
 java version "1.7.0_17"
 Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_17-b02)
 Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 23.7-b01, mixed mode)
 OS: Windows 7 64-bits.
```

[ASCII table](http://www.ascii-code.com/)

NOTE:

As @Black Panter added this is known bug

[JDK-4510618 : [Fmt-Nu] French thousands separator is non-breaking space](http://www.ascii-code.com/)

> WORK AROUND
>
> (1) Remove user's grouping separator (i.e. U+0020) in a String to be
>   parsed.
>
> (2) Replace user's grouping separator with the formatter's grouping
>   seperator (U+00A0) if it's inconvenient to remove all spaces.

Comment: I'm getting "java.text.ParseException: Unparseable number: "1 599,99 €"" on Java 1.7 when I run your code. On the other hand removing whitespaces does the trick.

Comment: Could you tell where that exception was thrown ? Or paste the output?

Comment: BTW. Removing group operator will always work for number as it is optional for format.

Comment: This line: "number = currencyInstance.parse("1 599,99 €");" throws the exception I pasted above. You're catching the exception, right? Removing the first space fixes it.

Comment: That's  odd. As the value in the last line is the print out of `string` variable. It might be that is defined in other way on your OS. But as far it goes for national standard it should work with space as group separator.

Comment: hm? the last line isn't a print but parsing or am I missing something?

Comment: @Vash, I am not sure how line `NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(Locale.FRANCE).parse("1 599,99 €");` is working in your case. It is throwing exception.

Comment: @MateuszDymczyk, The value there is copy paste from print out that was done before. It was added later to the script.

Comment: @Vash: which JDK are you using (Oracle or OpenJDK)? I'm pretty interested now because after checking Oracle's source code locale doesn't affect whitespaces in the number string.

Comment: @Jitendra, In my case is working as I was passing valid character. As I copy the output to use it later is input. When i have typed manually then i got error like you.

Comment: @MateuszDymczyk, the Oracle one.

Comment: @Vash, Good point. I was not aware of breaking and non breaking space.  So that means I should first replace breaking spaces with non-breaking one and then do the parsing.

Answer (score 1):

it is because of the space in your number `1 599`, it will throw a ParseException
Remove the space and it will work like a charm

But it is not supposed to throw an exception, as the document states

> Returns a Long if possible (e.g., within the range [Long.MIN_VALUE, Long.MAX_VALUE] and with no decimals), otherwise a Double. If IntegerOnly is set, will stop at a decimal point (or equivalent; e.g., for rational numbers "1 2/3", will stop after the 1). **Does not throw an exception;** if no object can be parsed, index is unchanged!

I just found this [**Link**](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=4510618)
states about a bug relating to this.

Comment: This is far from being true.

Comment: For French number you use `,` as decimal separator and ` ` (space) for group separator.

Comment: fails both with , and .

Comment: @Vash removing the whitespace works, but with the white space it throws a ParseException

Comment: @BlackPanther, If the character is invalid will thrown. If is correct then works as expected.

Comment: it is supposed to.. but its not.. i just found out this [**link**](http://bugs.sun.com/view_bug.do?bug_id=4510618)