# NumberFormat currency parsing failing "Unparseable number"

Tags: java, currency

NumberFormat throws ParseException when I try to parse "10,10 €".

```
@Test
public void get_currency_from_text() throws Exception {
    String moneyAsString = "10,10 €";
    //Do not use double for monetary values
    Double moneyAsDouble = 10.10;

    NumberFormat formatter = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(Locale.GERMANY);
    Double parsedMoney = formatter.parse(moneyAsString).doubleValue();
    assertEquals(moneyAsDouble, parsedMoney);
}
```

This is what I is thrown when I run the test

```
java.text.ParseException: Unparseable number: "10,10 €"
```

It works fine whenever I do this though:

```
@Test
public void get_currency_from_text() throws Exception {

    Double moneyAsDouble = 10.10;

    NumberFormat formatter = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(Locale.GERMANY);
    String moneyAsString = formatter.format(moneyAsDouble);
    Double parsedMoney = formatter.parse(moneyAsString).doubleValue();

    System.out.println(moneyAsString);
    //10,10 €

    assertEquals(moneyAsDouble, parsedMoney);
}
```

I suspect that it has something to do with the space, but I still don't know how to fix it, any ideas?

Comment: @Henry, the thing is that moneyAsString in the second example HAS the space and the € symbol, why does that work in that case?

Comment: You are mistaken. The second example doesn't have a space, it has a ['NO-BREAK SPACE' (U+00A0)](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/00a0/index.htm), which looks like a space, but isn't. It works if you change literal to `"10,10\u00a0€"`. --- Note: Whether the formatted string uses Space or Nbsp depends on the JDK library, both flavor (Oracle, other, ...) and version (even patch number).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seems like the space in "10,10 €" is not the right ASCII which the formatter is expecting.
It's clearly mentioned here ([Parse currency with symbol: Not all case working - Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19488923/parse-currency-with-symbol-not-all-case-working-java)) that The format class expect the char with code 160 which is describe as "Non-breaking space".

Comment: Code 30 is not space. Code 32 (decimal) is. Or code 20 (hex) is.